# Ugly colors on Saiku charts after upgrading to 3.0 CE

Tags: saiku

After I have migrated Saiku CE plugin (run within Pentaho CE) from 2.6 to 3.0, the colors of charts got pretty ugly and hard to read. They are all different types of red, which makes understanding charts very difficult.
Question is - can colors be somehow controlled and changed?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you still need an answer, but here it is.
You can change the colors in a file :
`[saiku_server_root]\tomcat\webapps\ROOT\js\saiku\render\SaikuChartRenderer.js`

Search for "options.colors" string, it's an array with all the color values you want Saiku to use.
In my case I use the base colors, which is the old set of colors used in Saiku :

`options.colors = ["#1f77b4", "#aec7e8", "#ff7f0e", "#ffbb78", "#2ca02c", "#98df8a", "#d62728", "#ff9896", "#9467bd", "#c5b0d5", "#8c564b", "#c49c94", "#e377c2", "#f7b6d2", "#7f7f7f", "#c7c7c7", "#bcbd22", "#dbdb8d", "#17becf", "#9edae5" ];`

Comment: Thanks for answering - Yes, I still need an answer :) Unfortunately my Pentaho does not have such file at all, and in ROOT it only has WEB-INF, and index.jsp. So, the thing has to be placed in some other js file - i'm looking for it now. Update: it does have this file, but it is placed here:./pentaho-solutions/system/plugin-cache/backups/saiku_1407748682452/ui/js/saiku/render/SaikuChartRenderer.js
./pentaho-solutions/system/plugin-cache/backups/saiku_1416839284672/ui/js/saiku/render/SaikuChartRenderer.js

Answer (score 1):

The right place to change that ugly colors is the file `biserver-ce\pentaho-solutions\system\saiku\ui\saiku.min.js`
Search for the substring `a.colors=["#AE1717","#AE5B17","#0E6868"];` and replace it with your colors array: `a.colors=["#1f77b4", "#aec7e8", "#ff7f0e", "#ffbb78", "#2ca02c", "#98df8a", "#d62728", "#ff9896", "#9467bd", "#c5b0d5", "#8c564b", "#c49c94", "#e377c2", "#f7b6d2", "#7f7f7f", "#c7c7c7", "#bcbd22", "#dbdb8d", "#17becf", "#9edae5" ];`